# How to make angularjs filter work only once?

Tags: angularjs

I have this filter:

```
filter:{ ClientId:details.client.Id }
```

Here how I use It:

```
  <uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="contract in details.contracts | filter:{ ClientId:details.client.Id } " is-open="false">
            <uib-accordion-heading>
                <div class="text-center">
                </div>
            </uib-accordion-heading>
            <div class="form-group">
                bla bla
            </div>
        </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

How can I make filter work only once when uib-accordion derective is created?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean. The purpose of a filter in an ng-repeat is to be run for each item in the list of items passed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contract in ::details.contracts | filter:{ ClientId:details.client.Id }`. This will evaluates whole expression once (ok, not once, until it becomes defined). But it also wont update expression when `details.contracts` changes.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

> ### When filters are executed
>
> In templates, filters are only executed when their inputs have changed. This is more performant than executing a filter on each $digest as is the case with expressions.
>
> There are two exceptions to this rule:
>
> In general, this applies only to filters that take primitive values as inputs. Filters that receive Objects as input are executed on each $digest, as it would be too costly to track if the inputs have changed.
>
> Filters that are marked as $stateful are also executed on each $digest. See Stateful filters for more information. Note that no Angular core filters are $stateful.

So in your case, so long as `details.client.Id` isn't triggered from some input's change event or isn't triggering a digest, your filter is running as performant as it can be.

Another way would be to call a controller method that has a cached value.  It won't prevent the filter from firing, but it will immediately return a cached value.  I don't recommend this though because angular filters are generally the prescribed solution for performant filtering solutions.

**controller method**

```
$scope.getCached = function(){
    if(cachedValue) return cachedValue
    return cachedValue = ...
}
```

**implementation**

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objs | filter:getCached()">
```